# Какие существенные изменения ожидаются в языках программирования высокого уровня?

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

Любой язык программирования, если он еще актуален, развивается, перенимает, добавляет что-то новое. Появляются новые с уже взвешенными подходами в своем проектировании, я имею ввиду учет плюсов и минусов других или предыдущих. Растет сложность выстраиваемых систем, происходит сращивание программ с сетью, с устройствами, друг с другом.

Интересно, что говорят в профессиональных кругах, на форумах, конференциях и т.д. о горизонте или перспективах в построении ЯП. Какие существенные (понимаю насколько обширна тема) изменения ожидаются в языках программирования высокого уровня? К чему, примерно, надо быть готовым программисту в ближайшие пять-десять лет?

Я **не прошу фантазировать**, я прошу рассказать о **реальных планах** реальных гуру-разработчиков, которые наверняка ими делятся.

**UPD** Были бы интересны ответы как по отдельным языкам, так и в общем.

Comment: Если здесь вопрос закроют, на [**Theoretical Computer Science**](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) попробуйте спросить. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну готовым надо быть всегда и ко всему. И зачем загадывать, что будет и в каких языках. По факту изучаете то, что нужно в данный момент. И у разных языков совершенно различные пути.

Comment: Вопрос очень интересный и сам с удовольствием пообсуждал бы эту тему. Но, перед тем, как задать такой вопрос, Вы забыли провести подготовительную работу (с участниками сайта) по смене допустимой тематики.  Вангую, что в течении часа его закроют.

Comment: А вот по поводу гуру Вы явно не по адресу. Тут таких нет.

Comment: @avp подготовительную работу? это как?

Comment: Например, поговорить со **многими** людьми о том, что неплохо бы разрешить такую тематику и громко заявить об этом на Мете.

Comment: @avp ну кто-то же наверняка слышал о реальных планах реальных гуру-разработчиков.

Comment: Подозреваю, что даже те, кто общается с гуру, сюда не заходят (а жаль)

Comment: Гадание - не самая интересная сфера. Планы разработчиков лишь одного языка слишком обильны даже для статьи, а тут вопрос про не один десяток таких языков.

Comment: @Other гадать конечно не нужно, в вопросе говорится о существенных изменениях и наверняка они выделяются на фоне менее существенных. Согласен, что автору ответа выпадает огромная ответственность по выделению самого существенного на его взгляд. От этого зависит судьба мира.

Comment: Тогда Ваш вопрос совершенно справедливо закрыли. Каждый будет тянуть одеяло в свою сторону. Начиная от восхваления своего языка, до схваток уровня StarWars из-за того, что важнее в новом стандарте будет.

Comment: @Other, если ответы будут, то мне, например, не взирая на их субъективность это будет интересно. А вы чего хотите?

Comment: @avp, холивары могут быть интересными, но это не значит что их можно тут устраивать. Есть флудильня, если хочется.

Comment: @Other, вообще-то что можно, а что нет решает де-факто активное большинство. Начнут холиварить, придется примириться.

Comment: @avp, этим и закончится. Интересны новинки? Читаем дайджесты. Остальное холиваром закончится, неоднократно проверено.

Comment: @Other, а что делают те, кто хочет эти дайджесты обсудить?

Comment: @avp, в комментах там, где его опубликовали. А ещё лучше - выбрать тему из бюллетени и её отдельно обсуждать.

Comment: @Other, а если они начнут открывать такие темы тут и обсуждать их в своих ответах? И что произойдет, если их будет действительно много?

Comment: @avp, зайдём с другой стороны - если Вы уверены что их будет **много**, то что будет с этой темой? Её тут закрыли, точка. Обсудить новинки - это хорошо, но это на хабр или тематический форум. Тут база вопросов и ответов, а не фантазий и мечтаний ИМХО.

Comment: @Other, закрыли, поскольку по делу отвечать некому. А некому, может еще и потому, что правила такие строгие и вахтеров многовато?

Comment: @avp, пресвятые ёжики, отвечайте, я же не против. Но не думаю что можно достойно обсудить подобное без форума или чата.

Comment: @avp, ну вот я могу по делу за Java рассказать, что будет в JDK 9, только это и так на каждом углу обсуждают. А через пару лет придется про 10ку писать.

Comment: @Nofate, таки поставь плашку что вопрос про быстро изменяемое :-)

Comment: Про небыстро изменяемое.

Comment: Вопросу неделя, а делиться секретами гуру-разработчиков никто не спешит.

Comment: @Nofate, на то они и секреты, чтобы никому!

Comment: @Nofate Напишите и сделайте общим. Кому надо, тот и обновит.

Comment: Что-то я не совсем понимаю, что тут делает этот вопрос. Meta - это ведь сайт для вопросов о родительском сайте (в данном случае ruSO)? А хотя... На ruSO его бы все равно закрыли за то, что "невозможно дать объективный ответ, вопрос порождает споры или дискуссии" и все в этом духе.

Comment: @smellyshovel под меткой [tag:диалоги-о-работе] мы тут пробуем обсуждать оффтопик )

Comment: @Nofate тогда все логично

Comment: @avp: на Stack Exchange сайте Physics [**нобелевский лауреат**](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooft) на момент написания данного сообщения имеет рейтинг под 3500. Возможно, на enSO есть специалисты подобного калибра. И Джона Скита, думаю, можно охарактеризовать как «гуру». Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

На текущий момент (конец лета 2017 года) планируемые изменения в C# — привлечение в язык большого количества функциональных выразительных средств, устранение `null`, более удобная асинхронность.

Из ближайших планов разработчиков языка — устранение «ошибки на миллиард долларов» ([необнуляемые указатели](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/features/NullableReferenceTypes/docs/features/NullableReferenceTypes/Nullable%20reference%20types.md)), расширение интерфейсов [включением имплементации](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md) (как в Java).

Из следующих проектов [асинхронные потоки](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/43) (как `IEnumerable<T>`, но получение следующего элемента асинхронное) и асинхронное уничтожение объектов, [records](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/records.md) + [pattern matching](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/patterns.md).

Более далёкий прицел — [discriminated unions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/113) + [type classes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164), [полиморфизм высшего уровня](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/339) (монады) и [кодогенерация на этапе компиляции](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/107).

Кроме того, планируется очень много синтаксических улучшений/упрощений, чтобы простые вещи было просто и запрограммировать. (Это можно назвать *всего лишь* синтаксическим сахаром, но он реально помогает программировать.)

Затем, отвлекаясь от языка, много внимания уделяется реальной кросс-платформенности, .NET Standard + Xamarin + nuget + ..., так что C# более не язык «только под Windows».

---

Резюмируя самое важное: асинхронность + элементы функционального программирования.

Answer (score 2):

- [Automatic parallelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization)   - Автоматическое преобразование последовательного кода в многопоточный.  Задача автоматического распараллеривания потоков предполагает избавить программистов от суеты и ошибок ручного распараллеривания.

(*ответ надеется быть дополненным заинтересованными участниками*)

Comment: Этой мечте лет 30 (как минимум). Неужели в этот раз осуществится?

Comment: Отчасти реализовано в Java Stream API. В других языках тоже встречается.

Comment: @D-side спасибо, теперь общий

Answer (score -5):

> К чему, примерно, надо быть готовым программисту в ближайшие пять-десять лет?

В ближайшие пять, десять лет будьте готовы реализовывать **алгоритмы** и **структуры данных**.

Возможно в будущем появятся такие базы данных. Как бы готовых модулей. Для определенной задачи. Берешь готовый алгоритм, для своей задачи, или готовую структуру данных. Использовал её, и поставил + или - . И всё сообщество видит, насколько эффективен данный алгоритм или подходит структура данных под задачу.

Comment: Обычные менеджеры пакетов, коих в современных языках хватает. Ruby и RubyGems, Python и PIP, Rust и Cargo, Haskell и Cabal, Haxe и Haxelib и многие другие. Это уже не будущее, это суровое настоящее. UPD: техническая неточность: в ответе говорится скорее о **репозиториях**, с которыми работает менеджер пакетов, но с ними та же история, они существуют и активно используются, а в каждом конкретном случае обычно есть ещё и один доминирующий репозиторий с удобным веб-интерфейсом, оценками и прочим.