# Вопросы–обсуждения формата «за жизнь» на Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: обсуждение, правила, диалоги-о-работе

Бывает, участники задают вопросы формата обсуждения, которые по сути своей не могут получить однозначного ответа. Например, [Какие существенные изменения ожидаются в языках программирования высокого уровня?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4588/) С другой стороны, подобные вопросы вызывают живой интерес у участников сообщества.

**Что мы хотим с ними делать?**

Очень важно понимать, почему такие вопросы закрываются на основном сайте.

- Они не несут практической пользы. *Наш сайт – база знаний всего русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков, диалогам за жизнь в ней не место.* Что хуже, обсуждение трендов – дело всегда неблагодарное. Большинство из нас в общих чертах примерно понимают, что произойдет, но точно не знает никто.
- Все ответы на них основаны на мнениях, а не на знаниях, что иногда порождает споры и ссоры.

По умолчанию все такие вопросы следует закрывать, а автору вопроса можно поднять вопрос в [общем чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Альтернативным решением может быть перенос таких вопросов на Мету. В этом случае следует сперва *задать жесткую допустимую структуру ответов* (пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [подобное обсуждение вопросов о работе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2423/)). Не имея критериев, мы можем провалиться на самое дно откровений, споров и скандалов, что, конечно же, недопустимо.

**Пожалуйста, предложите ваши варианты и, если вы видите место таким вопросам на Мете, укажите рекомендуемый формат для ответов.**

**Обновление**

"Почему бы нам всем просто не согласиться с тем, что у нас будут вопросы–опросники, в которых подразумевается обмен мнениями?" - потому что это будет уже не Stack Overflow.

Сайт создан для того, чтобы человек, где бы он ни находился физически, мог быстро получить квалифицированную помощь от коллег. Stack Overflow – это место решения профессиональных задач, которые возникают во время работы. Любой вопрос на сайте - это мини заметка в формате проблема–решение. Мы радеем за кристаллизацию знаний, чтобы прочтение любого вопроса или ответа занимало минимальное время для любого, кто пришел на сайт из поиска. Таким образом мы боремся с *вредоносным шумом*. Как результат, сайт стал знакомым каждому инструментом эффективного решения поставленных задач.

Теряет ли сообщество в числе оттого, что вопросы, на которые нельзя дать однозначный ответ, недопустимы на сайте? – Да, теряет. Но находит еще больше: именно сообществу Stack Overflow люди доверяют решение самых сложных задач.

Всё же Stack Overflow – это не машина решения задач, а люди (зачастую высокой квалификации), которым интересны некоторые дискуссионные вопросы. Как мне кажется, было бы здорово поделиться опытом таким образом, чтобы он был полезен. Для этого необходима строгая структура для подобных тем. Примером могут служить [списки литературы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/) с одной стороны и [вопрос об опыте нахождения первой работы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2423/) – с другой. Для случаев, когда структуру задать не удается, мы не раз наблюдали интересные диалоги в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: там "за жизнь" беседа велась по поводу того, что теряет ли ruSO от того, что закрывают вопросы, которые могли бы быть вполне "хорошими" в другом сообществе/подсайте когда ruSO разрастется и о том, что желание пропадает задавать вообще перспективные вопросы. Именно этот вопрос, как его автор, я не защищаю, просто размышляю. RuSO - великолепный ресурс, это однозначно.

Comment: Во многом @TimurVI прав, особенно в том, что желание спросить что-то нестандартное и узнать разные мнения напрочь исчезает. А вместе с этим уходит  и интерес к сайту (в т.ч. и к чтению вопросов и ответам на них). Опасения же "провалиться на самое дно" imho преувеличины, поскольку 99% вопросов всегда будут вполне "традиционными".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky было бы неплохо привести пример настоящего "вопроса за жизнь". Потому что пока и вы, и Barmaley в качестве вопроса за жизнь привели обычные онтопичные технические вопросы.

Answer (score 9):

Не стоит смешивать вопросы "за жизнь" и "интересные технические опросники".

---

Интересные технические опросники у нас легализованы.

- Code Golf - [Узаконим гольф?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/) (хотя лично я - против :)
- Вопросы по поиску библиотек -  [Что делать с вопросами про поиск библиотек/плагинов/инструментов/приложений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2615/) (при наличии четких критериев)
- Code Review - [Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/)

Вопрос [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113) из соседнего ответа, который на enSO закрыли - у нас бы вполне остался открытым как Code Golf.

Кроме того у нас частично легализованы вопросы про книги и учебные ресурсы в виде общего списка: [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/)

---

Вопрос, который приведен в качестве примера в посте выше - [Какие существенные изменения ожидаются в языках программирования высокого уровня?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4588/) - не опросник. На него вполне можно дать обоснованный ответ. Почти у всех популярных языков есть публичные roadmap-ы со списком планируемых фич. Компиляция нескольких таких roadmap-ов была бы полноценным объективным ответом.

Я бы сам с удовольствием почитал о планируемых языковых фичах в соседних стеках. Я вижу проблему только в том, что каждый из roadmap-ов достаточно обширен, и полноценный ответ был бы огромным. Даже сравнение существующих фич, вроде лямбд в C# и лямбд в Java, или генериков в C# и генериков в Swift - требует пары абзацев текста.

Т.е. такой вопрос просто слишком обширен. Обширность вопроса и невозможность написать полноценный краткий ответ обычно приводит к забрасыванию ответами-ссылками.

---

Вопросы "за жизнь" - это или холивары, или нетехническое нытье.

Вот примеры вопросов "за жизнь":

- [Как в сжатые сроки изучить разработку под Андроид? (del)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/)
- [Куда двигаться С++ программисту (del)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161859)
- [Java или C#, что нужнее сейчас и в перспективе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263536/)
- [Будущие перспективы программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73611/)
- [Вопрос о работе программиста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90010/)
- [Когнитивный диссонанс или правила жизни](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269968/)
- [Как быть недопрограммисту? Что делать? (del)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/253957/)
- [Карьерный рост веб-разработчика (del)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/186751/)
- [Програмить тяжело хочу уйти в системные аналитики (del)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/186751/)
- [Совет начинающим стартаперам (del)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/145470/)
- [Стажировка программистом за границей (del)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/116356/)

Общий признак таких вопросов - в них можно зайти, и, *не читая вопрос*, дать красивый ответ, начинающийся со слов

> Молодой человек, не там ищете. Надо заниматься не тем, что вам сейчас кажется перспективным, а тем, к чему у вас лежит сердце или что у вас лучше получается.

И этот ответ будет гарантированно заплюсован.

Конкретный пример: я могу открыть вопрос  [Как учить ребенка программировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105133/) и запостить там ответ:

> Надо учить ребенка не тому, что вам сейчас кажется перспективным, а поддерживать в нем то, что у него лучше получается, и к чему у него лежит сердце!

Такие вопросы - это обычное нетехническое нытье. Жизнь вообще тяжелая вещь, у всех бывают периоды сомнений. Всем приходится делать выбор. Но это не повод превращать SO в клуб психотерапевтов-любителей. В топку их.

Comment: Подскажите, можете ли вы предложить конкретные действия по оценке вопросов на предмет оставить/удалить для подобных вопросов? Как мне кажется, было бы здорово увидеть именно такие рекомендации. Сейчас, непонятно как именно определить, что удалять, а что нет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky мне нравится формулировка jfs - "практические вопросы по IT, у которых существует краткий полезный ответ на пару-тройку параграфов и встречающиеся у многих людей". И вообще я практически согласен с его ответом - но у него приведен неудачный пример.

Comment: В этом случае, как насчет такого: «Как мне найти работу, являясь студентом третьего курса ИТМО на кафедре ПМ, если у меня нет опыта? Знаю С++ и устройство компиляторов. Знаю основы Java.» Вопрос вполне себе прикладной, на три параграфа четких рекомендаций в виде шагов набрать можно. Тематический? Оставляем?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это не "практический вопрос *по IT*". Это практический вопрос, заданный IT-ником. Он выглядит тематическим только потому, что он *близок* большинству посетителей. Примерно так же, как и вопрос про обучение детей. Но это не значит, что хоть кто-то из посетителей сможет дать на него хороший ответ. Т.к. большинство посетителей искало первую работу один раз -  то ответы будут в стиле "напиши резюме и пошли в кучу мест".

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вопросы о работе были онтопиком довольно долго, и ни одного хорошего вопроса с хорошими ответами из них не получилось. Были ответы с наездами на PHP, были "без корочек никуда", были "корочки не нужны", были "учи что тебе ближе" - но это все непереносимый личный опыт. Т.е. читать про него (кому-то) интересно, но взять и применить к своей жизни - не получится.

Comment: Таким образом, вы вводите дополнительные критерии, как мне кажется, или уточняете значение термина «практический». Цель данного обсуждения – собрать такие критерии, чтобы всем было очевидно, чему быть, а чему нет. В некотором смысле, я согласен с @Barmaley, что должна быть «изюминка», но она для каждого своя. Было бы здорово увидеть в этом вопросе отзывы всех тех, кому интересны обсуждаемые в данном вопросе темы, чтобы понять, как мы будем выделять тематические вопросы от нетематических. Если вы видите четкие границы (пусть не все сразу), пожалуйста, укажите их!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я не вводил дополнительные критерии и не уточнял термин "практический". Я хочу видеть "вопросы по IT", а не "вопросы, которые инетерсны IT-никам". Обсуждаемая проблема должна быть "уникальна для разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального администрирования IT систем". "Как найти работу" - не уникальна. Не IT-ники тоже ищут работу. "Какое пиво вы любите" - не уникальна. Четкая граница - специфичность вопроса именно для IT.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хотите изюминку - придумывайте именно изюминку. "Давайте разрешим вопросы по поиску работы" - это не изюминка. Это просто предложение еще раз открыть категорию "вот тех некачественных холиварных вопросов, с нытьем, которые были разрешены, и которые оказались неинтересны кроме их авторов и пары очень настойчивых участников"

Answer (score 5):

Задрали этим древним вопросом [Как учить ребенка программировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105133/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) - такое ощущение, что кое-кому нечем больше заняться, кроме как писания бесполезных, нудных и зачастую вредных правил по типу [Взбесившегося принтера](http://varlamov.ru/701619.html).

Регулировать конечно надо, но в меру. А мера здесь лежит в аудитории/траффике сайта. Сейчас, конечно, опять выскочат из-за угла и начнут махать метриками, что траффик де растёт и все такое прочее. Верю, наверное растёт, не замерял не знаю, но верю. Вера исходит из понимания того, что сайт вылез из детских штанишек и работает. В эпоху Хэшкода (мильон лет назад), без таких вопросов/дискуссий как эти детские вопросы/ответы - сайт может и не стал бы тем кем стал, поэтому давайте не будем плеваться в сторону истории. Кто не помнит своей истории - дальше вы и сами можете продолжить.

Мне отчасти нравится позиция ТС:

> Теряет ли сообщество в числе оттого, что вопросы, на которые нельзя дать однозначный ответ, недопустимы на сайте? – Да, теряет.

Важно понимание простого факта, что русскоязычное сообщество SO (как и вообще любые русскоязычные сообщества), склонно и тяготеет к дискуссиям, самобичеванию, самокопанию, самоанализу ну и т.д. по типу кухонных посиделок. Это, если хотите, наш национальный психотип - это может нам/вам нравиться или не нравиться - но это факт. А факты нельзя отрицать их надо использовать.

Итого, мое мнение, дискуссии нужны. Вот как это организовать- этого я не знаю. Верю, понимаю, что в основном треде ruSO видимо это будет лишним. Но без разговоров за жизнь - сайт потеряет ту самую изюминку, которая и привлекает:

> Всё же Stack Overflow – это не машина решения задач, а люди (зачастую высокой квалификации), которым интересны некоторые дискуссионные вопросы.

Вот я тот самый с *высокой квалификацией*, вот что мне делать на этом сайте? Затем, чтобы объяснять школяру [смысл термина stateless](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614175/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/614181#614181)? или [выступать компилятором/дебаггером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619231/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception/619238#619238) в поиске его ошибок?

Мне интересно отвечать [например так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616278/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-java/618777#618777) или поучаствовать в обсуждении [такого вопроса-опроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611018/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-qt-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-android)

Должна быть изюминка, без изюминки неинтересно.

К сожалению у меня нет конкретного рецепта, как сделать чтобы ту самую изюминку не выкинули сгоряча. Вы же тот самый разумный принтер, который формулирует правила - формулируйте, с учетом или игнором моих мыслей, а мы аудитория/траффик, которая будет оценивать ваши правила.

**P.S.** Вот только не надо говорить, что мы/вы все вместе формулируем правила по которым работает сайт :) Мы уже достаточно взрослые люди и все понимаем.

Comment: Как учить ребенка программировать? - это просто топовый вопрос за жизнь, если не на нем примеры приводить - то на чем тогда? :)

Comment: По поводу "национального психотипа". Люди везде одинаковые. Нет никакого особого русского тяготения к самокопанию.  Т.е. русские думают, что оно есть - но точно так же копаться в себе любят и все остальные нации. Просто русские (скорее всего из-за языкового барьера) - этого не замечают. Вы же не лазите на англоязычные сайты поговорить "за жизнь"? Ну и опять же - причем тут вопрос "Недостатки использования Qt для Android" к разговорам "за жизнь?". Он что, о самокопании, специфическом для русского народа? Да вот точно такой же вопрос на enSO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460127/.

Comment: Люди везде одинаковые - типичная манипуляция. Люди конечно же везде разные. **Люди равные да, но разные.** Дикий масай в Африке и утонченный калифорнийский хипстер - конечно же у них совершенно разные психотипы, поведение, мировозрение, привычки, вероисповедание и проч. Так что давайте не будем :)

Comment: Манипуляция - это утверждать что русскоязычное сообщество SO больше тяготеет к "за жизнь", чем, скажем, англоязычное SO :) Есть определенные культурные различия, но склонность к самоанализу, сомнениям в себе, и прочей рефлексии - это неотъемлимая часть человеческой натуры. Да, у масаев скорее всего нет времени поныть, но вот разработчики из развитых стран копаются в себе не реже, чем средний посетитель ruSO.

Comment: Вообще я за дискуссионные вопросы на технические темы. И такие вопросы тут обычно остаются открытыми. Как "опросники" закрывают или нетехническое нытье, или холивар "C# vs Java". Нетехническое нытье у нас (вроде бы) разрешено на мете, но к приходу модератора в такой вопрос его уже успевают сильно заминусовать :(

Answer (score 4):

*Безоговорочное* закрытие вопросов-опросников это хороший пример
[cargo-cult
programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)—выполнение
ритуальных действий без понимания мотивации (зачем они вообще
нужны). См. также [Grandma's Cooking
Secret](http://www.snopes.com/weddings/newlywed/secret.asp) (к примеру
историю с *"Yes, but honey, we had cats!"*).

Правила, которые хороши и даже *жизненно необходимы* для [сайта с
миллионами
посетителей](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#/!traffic),
могут по другому себя проявлять на [сайте с порядка сотней активных
участников](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/341448/number-of-active-experts-per-week#graph).

Из ["Good Subjective, Bad
Subjective"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/):

> Most forums and chat rooms have a scale problem. As in, they don't.

Популярный сайт, на котором небольшая часть вопросов за строгие рамки
выходит, лучше сайта строгого по форме, но который никто не читает.

Нужно быть осторожными: [опыт с одним сайтом
Programmers.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/137096)
показывает, что вредно иметь сайт в формате Stack Overflow, на котором
вопросы-опросники по IT преобладают.

С другой стороны, подобные вопросы популярны и могут новых посетителей
привлечь, к примеру, [Как учить ребенка
программировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/105133/23044) (аналог
[Best ways to teach a beginner to
program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3088/4279) или [How to best teach a group of children how to code?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13499626))

Чтобы ограничить вред от подобных вопросов, можно обязательную заметку
в каждый такой вопрос добавлять, которая в паре предложений излагает
[требования к хорошим Stack Overflow
вопросам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): (пересказ) «практические
вопросы по IT, у которых существует краткий полезный ответ на
пару-тройку параграфов и встречающиеся у многих людей».

Если *если* доля таких вопросов станет слишком большой, скажем более
10% (пару десятков в день), тогда можно подумать о дальнейших
ограничениях (закрытии при превышении квоты, перенос на Мету, если от
этого больше вреда чем пользы не будет, итд).

Текущая [доля за 2016 год: менее 3% для
вопросов-опросников](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289797/137096).

Сайт это живой организм, не следует путать желаемое взрослое состояние
и *пути его достижения* по мере роста (молоко может быть полезное для
детей, хотя многие взрослые могут его не переваривать). Вопросы-опросники
могут помочь расти и поддерживать сайт, не являясь целью существования
сайта.

Comment: Как учить ребенка программировать? - аналог Best ways to teach a beginner to program? только по ужасному качеству ответов. У нас есть вопросы со списком ценных ссылок для начинающих - [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/) и прилинкованные к нему.

Comment: И, если честно - "Как учить ребенка программировать" - это просто древний, когда-то давно заплюсованный треш. В нем нет ни одного "краткого полезного ответа". Кроме " 
ребенку нужно во всем давать возможность себя попробовать: и в футболе, и в танцах, и в творчестве, и в программировании....а там он сам вам подскажет, что ему больше нравиться и к чему у него склонности...нельзя навязывать детям то, что хочешь делать сам!!!" :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Критерии оценки ответов на вопросы-опросники совсем другие. Вот видите, конкретный пример вопроса такой интересный, что вы не удержались от того, чтобы процититировать ответ оттуда (который вероятно близок к вашему личному субъективному мнению)—ничего более того что люди, незнакомые со Stack Overflow тыкнулись бы на ссылку и узнали что Stack Overflow на русском существует и не нужно от подобных вопросов. Остальное направлено, чтобы ограничить вред от таких вопросов; суть моего ответа: думайте в терминах tradeoffs: что получаем, что теряем—не следуя слепо примеру большого сайта.

Comment: я пишу развернутый ответ ниже с примерами вопросов. но вообще, насколько я вижу, хорошие опросники у нас разрешены. Просто  "Как учить ребенка программировать" к ним не относится. Мне в жизни не захочется применять ответы из него на практике (у меня трое детей, если что). И вопросы "как учить ребенка ООП" и как учить ребенка SQL" от того же автора - не лучше.

Comment: @PashaPash: [какие из 6 пунктов (определяющие "хорошесть" субъективного вопроса)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) нарушены по-вашему для этого вопроса

Comment: 1 (нет why), 2 (short answers), частично 3 (в ответах - слишком много opinions, нет experiences непосредственно обучения, и в основном воспоминаний "как учили меня", а не реального опыта обучения других), частично 4 (facts and references - то же, что и в 3 - нет упоминания реальных фактов обучения и результатов).

Comment: конкретно этот вопрос плох тем, что он задан не тем людям (и не на том сайте). Это вопрос "как учить детей" заданный тем, кого учили (тем, кто сами не намного старше детей). А не тем, кто может хорошо на него ответить - pro педагогам. Будь у нас сайт "учителя.stackoverflow.com" - вопрос был бы отличным!

Comment: @PashaPash: это ваше субъективное мнение. Не вижу смысла продолжать дискуссию--есть доводы (на сайте Q&A по программированию, смешно говорить, что вопрос не для той аудитории), но дискуссия не имеет отношения к текущему вопросу (представьте что я привёл пример субъективного вопроса, который лично вам нравится), кроме того что является прекрасной иллюстрацией, что субъективные вопросы легко к спорам ведут.

Comment: хм, наоборот - смысл продолжать как раз есть. Т.е. я не против разрешить субъективные вопросы, не нарушающие 6 пунктов по вашей ссылке выше. Но хотелось бы увидеть пару примеров таких вопросов, не попадающих под текущий список разрешенного (гольф и прочее). Потому что сейчас ваш ответ воспринимается как "разрешить все вопросы о жизни потому что они не вредят". Вот у меня в ответе есть ссылки на вопросы о жизни - какие из них, по вашему мнению, стоит оставить?

Answer (score 4):

> Очень важно понимать, почему такие вопросы закрываются на основном сайте.

Да. Но тут не всё так просто. Изначально на SO они были разрешены. Но потом, с ростом числа пользователей, с появлением других сайтов, тематика стала сокращаться. Отделился code colf, code review, software recommendations и многие другие.

У нас нет таких масштабов, у нас нет параллельных сообществ - у нас есть только ruSO. Так почему же мы должны следовать максимально урезанной тематике основного SO?

**Мы наоборот должны разрешить всё, что было разрешено на SO, когда его масштаб был похож на наш.** Это позволит получать интересные вопросы и привлекать людей.

Вывод: разрешить, но только если вопрос интересен.

Comment: Вопросы–опросники, на сколько я могу знать, никогда не были разрешены на SOen. Совершенно верно, при росте интереса к определенным тематикам, запускались новые сообщества. Что еще немаловажно, большинство сообществ стартовали [через Зону 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Это означает, что была четка структура того, как должны выглядеть вопросы. Причины закрытия, к слову, одни, на все сайты. Чтобы разрешить какую–либо тематику, необходимо четко обозначить границы. Вопрос именно об этом: как вы видите эти границы? Пример – [инспекция кода](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, границы: вопрос интересен минимум десятку пользователей, поставивших плюс. И вообще, а на хэшкоде как было? Там же запрета на такие вопросы не было - зачем теперь бросаться запрещать?

Comment: Граница в виде интересе – может не подойти. На мой взгляд, нам необходимо четко определить, какие вопросы допустимы и как на них следует отвечать, учитывая всю специфику SO.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, может не подойти, а может и подойти. Надо же попробовать, чтобы узнать. И всё-таки, как было на хэшкоде?

Comment: На ХэшКоде было два случая. Каждый вопрос рассматривался индивидуально. 1) Вопрос можно было уложить в формат, а ответы были действительно полезны. 2) Мы просто прозевали и не успевали закрыть/удалить вопрос до того, как участники опубликуют ответы (после получения ответа мы, в основном, никогда не удаляли вопросы).

Answer (score -4):

У меня такое предложение:

#### Удаляем вопросы "за жизнь"

Если вопрос буквально "за жизнь" вроде [нужно ли высшее образование?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430413/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82) или [про работу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/90010/220571), то я либо за перенос, либо за удаление с сайта таких вопросов. Не вижу никакой полезности в этих вопросах.

#### Оставляем вопросы с "субъективностью"

Если вопрос субъективный (связанный с выбором технологий, библиотек и подходов), то я за то, чтобы такие вопросы оставили. Выбор технологий, библиотек и подходов — считаю важным и полезным. Поэтому давайте разрешим такие вопросы либо безотносительно, либо если они интересные (критерий интересности можно затем будет выбрать, допустим вопрос с +10).

#### Оставляем увлекательные вопросы

Если вопрос увлекательный (подобен [Strangest languate feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature)) и любопытный, то бы такие вопросы оставлял, но только если они действительно интересные (критерий интересности можно затем будет выбрать, допустим вопрос с +10). Я бы не отказался если бы у нас подобные вопросы не закрывались.

Что по сути даст закрытие? Невозможность давать новые ответы. Я не вижу в этом выигрыша для многих подобных вопросов, особенно когда можно добавить что-то кардинально новое и соответственно потенциально полезное.

Comment: Сколько бы плюсов не получили подобные вопросы, они останутся вопросами–опросниками мнений, которым нет места на основном сайте, как минимум на Stack Overflow, по своей природе. К сожалению, данное предложение неосуществимо.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А у нас нельзя иметь отдельные правила? Пусть на enSO так нельзя, а у нас будет можно.

Comment: Можно, но не такие. Подобные вопросы на основном сайте противоречат самой идеи Stack Overflow (сайт, где решают рабочие вопросы, на котором нет разговоров за жизнь).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я переписал ответ, потому что сначала не так понял вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос–опросник (про технологии или про работу – не важно) сам по себе не может быть субъективным. Если вопрос про «лучшие практики в контексте вот такого задания» – это прекрасный вопрос, который прямо сейчас можно публиковать в виде вопрос+ответ. Еще одним вариантом может быть вопросы [про литературу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/) – такие вопросы крайне полезны.

Comment: То есть мы можем взять отдельно взятую тему, которая крайне интересна всем и рассмотреть ее как можно детальней всем сообществом (общий вопрос с одним ответом). Формат такого вопроса – полезные знания, но никак не дискуссии. Если вопрос подразумевает дискуссии или обсуждения основанные на мнениях, то по умолчанию ему нет места на Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, дискуссии и высказывание мнений - это не одно и то же. Хотя и в дискуссиях ничего плохого нет.