# Вопросы на смежную с программированием тематику

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Столкнулся с тем, что хочется узнать организацию процесса работы в различных кодерских коллективах. Такую информацию ни у кого не узнаешь,  только от программистов, которые работают в данной сфере, и это у них не хобби.

Ресурсов где бы нашлось такое количество подобных людей как на SO я не знаю. С одной стороны подобные вопросы имеют прямое отношение к программированию но с другой подобные холивары участники SO не поддерживают. Ведь была же метка [нытье](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5) на хешкоде - почему бы не вернуть ее?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57343/discussion-on-question-by-perfect------).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Вопросы–обсуждения формата «за жизнь» на Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4589/23044)

Comment: [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе] - нет?

Comment: А метка [meta-tag:нытьё], внезапно, есть на Мете.

Comment: @D-side и синоним [meta-tag:нытье] к ней есть, просто в посте ссылка на метку основного сайта (которой нет).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но раньше-то [была](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/131/178988), причём, ты [говорил](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/985/178988), что она останется ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy я имел в виду метку на Мете. Только сейчас понял, что она когда-то была и на основном сайте.

Comment: Можешь почитать про Agile и Scrum. Это как бы основные шаблоны работы в компании

Comment: @giik0n, это основные шаблоны работы _в какой_ компании?

Answer (score 10):

> хочется узнать организацию процесса работы

Это довольно широкое понятие. Если вы можете задать конкретный и четкий вопрос об организации разработки — задавайте.

Примеры вопросов, которые *мне* кажутся хорошими:

- В процессе разработки фичи есть этап тестирования и этап ревью кода. В каком порядке они должны идти? Нужно ли перетестировать после правок по ревью и переревьюить после правок по тестам?
- Как зафиксировать принятый в команде стиль кодирования в конфигурационном файле, так чтобы он автоматически использовался и обновлялся в IDE у каждого разработчика и на CI-сервере?
- Как связать JIRA с репозиторием, чтобы закрывать задачи в JIRA с помощью "fixes #1234" в сообщении коммита?
- Если в проекте совсем нет (юнит-)тестов, как определить, что покрывать тестами в первую очередь?
- Как фиксировать и передавать знания об архитектуре проекта?

Примеры вопросов, которые мне кажутся неподходящими для сайта:

- Всё что угодно про зарплату и трудоустройство.
- Как лучше собеседовать технических специалистов? (Я бы предложил это задать на Мете.)
- Нужно ли всем приходить на работу к 7, 8, 9, 10 утра?
- Как лучше/проще перейти на скрам, канбан, TDD и тёмную сторону силы?

Вопросы этой категории можно пообсуждать в чатике.

Comment: 1. А чем вопрос про собеседования не угодил? 2. [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе].

Comment: @Qwertiy ну диалоги-то у нас на мете. И про собеседования, как мне кажется, лучше на мету.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тем, что собеседование — это из области прикладной психологии, а не программирования?

Comment: @VladD, а как же техническая часть?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, техническая сторона означает по сути тест на умение работать в стрессовой ситуации, и при этом мило улыбаться и шутить. При условии, понятно, хоть сколько-нибудь адекватных программистских умений. Всё равно реально сложные задачи на собеседовании давать нельзя.

Comment: @VladD, некоторые умудряются заваливать элементарные, причём не только на собеседовании...