# Являются ли вопросы по проектному менеджменту и методологиям разработки допустимыми?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика

В процессе работы в команде в качестве участника или начинающего управленца часто могут возникать вопросы по настройке рабочего процесса в разработке ПО. С такими задачами часто не получается справиться и приходится пытаться изобрести велосипед, что чревато наступлением на грабли, на которые наступали тысячи других, что не есть хорошо.

Участники нашего сообщества могут активно помогать с решением подобных вопросов в связи с наличием опыта, но отнесение к онтопику кажется очень отдаленным, с другой стороны на SE нет более близкого по тематике сообщества на русском языке.

Примеры возможных вопросов:

- Как распределять задачи между программистами в рамках методологии X?
- Как правильно оценивать сложность выполнения задач в Scrum?
- Заказчик поставил задачу в формулировке (приведена выжимка из
  формулировки), какие вопросы нужно ему задать для формализации задачи
  или же как объяснить невыполнимость задачи в рамках имеющихся
  ресурсов?
- Поставил задачу программисту составить прототип ПО за 2 недели, он
  уже дважды просрочил время и снова просит продлить сроки, что делать
  в подобных ситуациях? Продлевать срок вновь кажется безумием, а если
  его уволить, то временные издержки могут увеличиться сильно больше,
  чем запрашиваемое время продления.

**Проблема:** на такие вопросы трудно дать объективно верный ответ, часто он будет исходить из личного опыта, трудно выбрать лучший ответ. Однако лучший ответ можно выбирать например по наиболее глубокому рассмотрению вопроса и, например, по количеству отсылок к известным статистикам / публикациям. Также лучший ответ это не только самый точный ответ, но и тот ответ который больше всего помог спрашивающему. Отношение к онтопику сильно притянуто.

**Польза:** привлечение трафика и влияние на качество работы команд разработчиков, можно делиться знаниями в этой достаточно важной для разработчиков области.

Comment: такие вопросы обычно выглядят либо как _порождающие бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях._, либо слишком общими - а, следовательно, их стоит закрыть :)

Comment: @Grundy формально - да, но вопросы могут нести потенциальную пользу для сообщества

Comment: Из 4 примеров, только первый можно хоть как-то формализовать и ответить, остальные - порождают дискуссии :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопросы–обсуждения формата «за жизнь» на Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4589/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: @älёxölüt имхо, вопросы обсуждаемые в указанном топике не имеют общего с этими

Comment: имеют, да ещё и самое непосредственное: 1. (из этого вопроса) «на такие вопросы трудно дать объективно верный ответ». 2. (из указанного вопроса) «"Почему бы нам всем просто не согласиться с тем, что у нас будут вопросы–опросники, в которых подразумевается обмен мнениями?" - потому что это будет уже не Stack Overflow.»

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не соглашусь, это не вопросы вида "что лучше - яблоки или груши?", ответить на вопросы подобного рода можно гораздо более объективно опираясь на опыт своих компаний, литературу, анализ публикаций и статистики от других и т.д. Данные вопросы гораздо ближе к пограничному случаю.

Comment: Ну да, онтопик. Но они все будут закрыты как opinion based )

Comment: В программировании тоже много вопросов на которые нельзя дать объективно верный ответ - но это же не значит, что нужно всё программирование закрывать. Ведь не все 100% вопросов по проектной работе будут opinion-based, не 90%, не 80% (не знаю, сколько - просто показываю, что подход "сколько граммов вешать" неверен. Как показывает практика, зачастую и op-based вопросы люди умеют обсуждать конструктивно и наоборот, любой увести в оффтопик. Уже и сейчас можно обсуждать ПМов как вопросы имеющие отношение к программированию, пусть и многое в закрывашках будет. Нужно задавать вопросы полгода, чтобы

Comment: потом приводить их в качестве примеров, когда будет определяться нужна ли такая тема или нет. И надо уточнить, как дела обстоят с инициативами и регламентами по их принятию - не уверен, что точно понимаю, как сейчас принято проводить подобные вещи.

Comment: @yolosora, по здравому смыслу эти вопросы допустимы, но в рамках действующих законов (правил сайта) и в сложившейся обстановке (обилие законопослушных активных закрывашек, и похоже, потеря интереса к общению (а ответы-комментарии на подобные вопросы это в первую очередь общение) у ранее активных членов сообщества) такие вопросы обречены

Answer (score 3):

Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся ... к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального администрирования IT систем

"*Как распределять задачи между программистами в рамках методологии X*" - подходит, так как это проблема, уникальная для разработки ПО.

"*Увольнять ли программиста, который не укладывается в сроки*" - не подходит, так это проблема управления персоналом, которая в равной мере может относиться к любой отрасли, а не только к разработке ПО.